# ionic2 performance issues while page transitions

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am developing the ionic 2 applications for mobile. But i try to move from one page to another(i.e, login page to dashboard) is taking so much time. I have done pages with static not dynamic pages.

I just included the following script files in the index.html,

```
<script src="../node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- Polyfill needed for platforms without Promise and Collection support -->
  <script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
  <script src="build/js/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <!-- the bundle built from the app's source code -->
  <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- google maps script is loaded last as to not block rendering -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

could any one guide me to improve the page transition?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your code, but for info on how to correctly implement Google maps, see here: http://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-advanced-google-maps-component-in-ionic-2/